# How to get the same SHA3 hash as soliditySHA3(ethereumjs-abi) returns using web3.sha3 in js?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereumj, sha3

I'm trying to hash a message as shown here:

```
function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) {
  return ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [contractAddress, amount],
  );
}
```

how can I use `web3.sha3` instead of `ABI.soliditySHA3` to get the SHA3 hash correctly, is there any difference anyway? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In web3 version 1.2.6, we have the following:

- web3.sha3(string) [Reference](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#sha3)

This method only takes an input as a string and calculates the sha3 equivalent of the input.

In order to achieve what you are trying to accomplish with `ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3` you should use `web3.utils.soliditySha3`

- web3.utils.soliditySha3 [Reference](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3)

Will calculate the sha3 of given input parameters in the same way solidity would. This means arguments will be ABI converted and tightly packed before being hashed.

```
function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) {
  // the types are auto-detected
  return web3.utils.soliditySHA3(contractAddress, amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here maybe this will help https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3

OR

This is actually implemented in ethereumjs-abi:

```
var abi = require('ethereumjs-abi')
var BN = require('bn.js')

abi.soliditySHA3(
    [ "address", "address", "uint", "uint" ],
    [ new BN("43989fb883ba8111221e89123897538475893837", 16), 0, 10000, 1448075779 ]
).toString('hex')
```